# How to add a second owner of a folder using terminal on Mac?

Tags: permissions, terminal, osx, chown

On Mac using terminal and "chown" command I can set owner for a folder like this:

```
sudo chown -R _www somefolder
```

However this replaces me with _www.
I.e. I'm not in the list of owners anymore.

[image]

I then have to open folder properties in Finder, add myself as a second owner and set permissions using the GUI.

[image]

And this is what the ACL looks like:

[image]

Is there a way to add TWO owners using terminal?
In other words how to add a second owner to a folder using terminal?
Not necessarily chown.

PS: Just in case.. on the screenshots users "_www" and "Oleg (Я)" have permissions "Read and write".

Comment: How do the permissions of the file with two owners look like in terminal. I doubt the Mac does this via POSIX file attributes, but via some ACL stuff.

Comment: You can't add a second owner. You may check for ACLs, if ordinary group-based security permission is not enough. You may also consider to own the file by a third user (root, nobody, or any neutral third account), and giving the access to *both* of users by group-based rules or by acls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer (type this in Terminal):

```
sudo chmod +a 'Oleg allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity' somefolder
```

Where 'Oleg' is a user name and 'somefolder' is a folder name in question.

The permissions inside single quotes after the 'allow' keyword are just copied from the output of `ls -le`

Now both users '_www' and 'Oleg' can read, write files and subdirectories, etc.

That was the intention.

Strictly speaking yes, you can not add a second "owner" in POSIX attributes sense, e.g. via Chown.

However in Mac you can give owner-like permissions to numerous users via ACL like Philippos commented (thanks for hinting).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because a Unix file have one owner, try to use a group instead.

Comment: Side note: surprising, but in Unix, the Owner and the Group are both a single integer, and nothing forbids for multiple users to have the same user-id. Thus, in the view of the kernel permission checking, there is no essential difference between uid and gid.

Comment: @peterh "two users" with the same uid are not "two users" but one user with two names.  The uid is what defines a user, not the name.   Also, "*there is no essential difference between uid and gid*" is just nonsense - were you drunk when you wrote that?

Answer (score 1):

this is a [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

X:problem, how can two user access same file, with same right ?

solution I use multiple chown => Y:problem

### Solution for X problem

according to http://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/acl.html

you can use

```
 chmod +a "allow Oleg list,search,add_file,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown"
 chmod +a "allow _www list,search,add_file,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown"
```

I can't test it right now, I don't have mac OS 10.5 available.

You might replace the long string above with the result of `ls -e`

### Y:solution: I try to use multiple chown.

This is not possible:
Unix/Linux/OS X's file have only one owner at a time.